# Create image with links (URL) in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am creating an image that will be used in an email signature on Outlook. I have selected the different elements and added the appropiate links using the Attributes window in Ai. However, when I save the image I cannot get the links to work. I have saved this as a jpeg, png and gif with no luck. I have used the Save for Web, Export As and Save for Screens.

Just need a little guidance.

Comment: I would save the image in Illustrator and add the link in afterward when creating the signature in Outlook. Some people have suggested adding a hyperlink to the image in Word and the copy->paste into your signature. Or you could write HTML for the signature yourself in Notepad or use an online editor like JSFiddle.

Comment: Well, that is true but I have multiple links on the image.. social media icons.

Answer (score 1):

Do a bit of research before loading links in to an email using images as buttons - some mail providers may treat your email as spam and junk the incoming mail before it gets read. 
With our latest email footer I decided to embed the images and enter a text link beneath and beside - don't think its any less professional and is clear in the browser what you want the recipient to do, because it looks like a simple link.

Answer (score 0):

**Slice Tool** is made for this.

in Illustrator, it'll separate the slices into individual images, when you Save for Web (`File > Export > Save for Web`) then you'd have to assemble them yourself with an html table layout.

alternatively, Photoshop's Slice Tool is more robust, as you can add in URLS to the slices. and when exporting it'll create the html table layout for you, with all links already done for you (if using Save for Web). from there you can copy/paste it into your email signature.

Comment: So - I did this In Ai, added links to the slices, was disappointed to see no html export  (As Photoshop). Does the html that displays when you preview allow you to Copy & Paste workif I were to paste it in an email sig?